# Disable and enable button after checking some condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have this button here

```
<button className={Classes.Button}
    disabled={!isEnabled}
    type="submit">
        {buttonText}
</button>
```

which should be disabled or enable after checking the value of some of my inputs.
the conditions

```
const canBeSubmitted = () => {
    return (
      customerData.firstNameState.length > 0 && // TextInput
      customerData.emailState.length > 0 && // TextInput
      customerData.companeyState.length > 0 && // TextInput
      customerData.selected.length > 0 &&   // Dropdown
      customerData.agree === true // checkbox for terms
    );
  };
  let isEnabled = canBeSubmitted();
```

BTW: The agree checkbox is checked by its handler and works fine.
The agree value is false in the state and the handler

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    const field = event.target.id;
    if (field === "firstName") {
      setFirstName({ firstName: event.target.value });
    } else if (field === "email") {
      setEmail({ email: event.target.value });
    } else if (field === "country") {
      setSelected({ country: event.target.value });
    } else if (field === "agree") {
      setAgree(!agree);
      console.log(agree);
    }
  };
```

but always return false. what am I missing?

Please help me out

Comment: what value are you passing in the checkbox? `===` is a strict equality comparison operator if you passing true as a string then it may cause the issue.

Comment: you are checking a lot of things, perhaps you should comment out all of them and only comment one back in to see which statement is causing the problem. Also why do you have !isEnabled and not just isEnabled?

Comment: @devin I did what you suggest thanks, the problem is coming from the first 3 conditions. But how to check if the user has fielded the input?

Comment: if `costumerData.selected` is a checkbox, you shouldn't be checking for its length for validity.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa thanks, no costumerData.selected is a dropdown, agree is a checkbox for terms, and the other 3  are text input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm correct, your 'state' isn't changing because of how you're changing 'state variables' in `handleChange` fat arrow function.

I could be wrong depending on how your 'state' is structured.

I'm assuming your 'state' is structured like this.

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
const [agree, setAgree] = useState(false);
```

1. Fix your `handleChange` function.

```js
// Commented out your possibly erroneous code.
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const field = event.target.id;

    if (field === "firstName") {
        // Fix here.
        // setFirstName({ firstName: event.target.value }); ❌
        setFirstName(event.target.value); ✅
    } else if (field === "email") {
        // Fix here.
        // setEmail({ email: event.target.value }); ❌
        setEmail(event.target.value); ✅
    } else if (field === "country") {
        // Fix here.
        // setSelected({ country: event.target.value }); ❌
        setCountry(event.target.value); ✅
    } else if (field === "agree") {
        // Fix here.
        // setAgree(!agree); ❌
        setAgree(event.target.checked); ✅
        console.log(agree);
    }
};
```

2. You can then perform your validation like this:

```js
const canBeSubmitted = () => {
    return (
    firstName.trim().length && // TextInput
    email.trim().length && // TextInput
    country.trim().length && // Dropdown
    agree // checkbox for terms
    );
};
```

3. It appears your also have a typo here for 'countryState':

```js
customerData.companeyState.length > 0 && // TextInput
```

4. It looks like there is a full stop after `&&` operator in your code.

```js
customerData.selected.length > 0 &&.   // Dropdown
```

## Addendum

@Harry9345, you can as well get rid of the `handleChange` completely.

*Full source code below*. **Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fog-vp19s?file=/src/App.js

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [agree, setAgree] = useState(false);

  const canBeSubmitted = () => {
    const isValid =
      firstName.trim().length && // TextInput
      email.trim().length && // TextInput
      country.trim().length && // Dropdown
      agree; // checkbox for terms

    if (isValid) {
      document.getElementById("submitButton").removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("submitButton").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
    console.log({ firstName, email, country, agree });
  };

  useEffect(() => canBeSubmitted());

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="" method="post" id="form">
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First name:</label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          value={firstName}
          onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="email">Email Address:</label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="country">Choose a country:</label>
        <br />
        <select
          id="country"
          name="country"
          value={country}
          onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="">Select..</option>
          <option value="1">USA</option>
          <option value="2">Canada</option>
          <option value="3">Algeria</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="agree"
          id="agree"
          onClick={(e) => setAgree(e.target.checked)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="agree"> I agree.</label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy really appreciate your help, That DOT  " . " is a typo when was typing code here,   I switch to react-hooks-form as it was much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use state instead of variable:

I added some example:

```html
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const canBeSubmitted = () => {
    return checked ? setIsDisabled(true) : setIsDisabled(false);
  };

  const onCheckboxClick = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    return canBeSubmitted();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" onClick={onCheckboxClick} />
      <button type="submit" disabled={isDisabled}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-shadow-r99jm?file=/src/App.tsx:0-67)

Of course it's just a sample of code and not very efficient.